# While solving for partial autocorrelation (PACF) values in matrix form, why don't we use Cramer's rule in coming up with the solution?

Tags: time-series, matrix, acf-pacf

While solving for partial auto correlation (PACF) values in matrix form, why don't we use Cramer's rule in coming up with the solution?

Comment: A google search for "pacf cramers rule" will show that some people do use it. https://www.google.com/search?q=pacf+cramers+rule

Comment: This algorithm doesn't have very good numerical or computational properties, though.  (Computing all those determinants is time consuming.)